# Работа с веткой после мерджа

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

Допустим, у меня была ветка `anotherBranch`. Я слил ее в `master`. Могу ли я дальше с ней работать? К примеру, захотел изменить функционал, который выполнялся в ветке `anotherBranch`, то логически делать ее там, чем создавать еще одну. Или после слияния ветка уже неактивна?

Comment: логично для новой функциональности сделать новую ветку. Не бойтесь создавать новые ветки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> захотел изменить функционал, который выполнялся в ветке anotherBranch, то логически делать ее там, чем создавать еще одну

На самом деле в git логичнее создать новую ветку для новой работы, чем продолжать работать в старой.

Формулируйте задачу, которую решаете, в названии ветки. Скажем у вас была ветка **feature/add_authorization_form** и вы вмержили ее в **master**. Затем оказалось, что в одном из браузеров уезжает верстка. В этом случае лучше создать новую ветку **feature/fix_authorization_form_layout**. Так сразу понятно, где вы добавили новую форму, а где просто пофиксили баг.

Более того, очень часто ветки удаляют сразу в момент мержа, и при мерже сворачивают все коммиты ветки в один (`git merge --squash`). В этом случае, когда работа над веткой закончена, от нее остается только один коммит в мастере и вся история мастера представляет собой историю добавления фич и баг-фиксов (один коммит - одна фича или фикс).

То есть не рассматривайте feature-ветки, как что-то долгоживущее. Они нужны только для того, чтобы изолировано сделать кусок работы.

Answer (score 1):

термин «ветка» («branch») — явно неудачный (в контексте сущностей, которыми манипулирует программа *git*).

ведь под словом «ветка» мы обычно подразумеваем нечто, имеющее «начало»/«основание», (как минимум один) «конец» и «что-то между ними».

в программе же *git* сущность, обозначаемая этим термином, представляет собой всего лишь **указатель** на один-единственный коммит.

пока вы не удалили этот указатель, вы можете им пользоваться сколько душе угодно.

Comment: да, но этот указатель однозначно идентифицирует как минимум конец, а начало легко находится.

Comment: «легко» – только в локальном логе того хранилища, где указатель был создан. да и то пока лог не очищен.

Comment: для иллюстрации «почему сложно»: создайте новый указатель, добавьте к нему коммит, создайте в этом месте ещё один указатель, добавьте по коммиту к обоим. а после этого, не заглядывая в лог, попробуйте определить, где же «начало» у **каждого** из двух указателей.

Comment: конечно сложно, если не знать математику. А если теорию графов хоть чуточку почитать, то все стает просто и понятно

Comment: только гадание на кофейной гуще поможет точно определить, какой из двух указателей (из примера выше) был создан раньше.